# ngif else is not working in AngularJs 4

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I am getting an error and it says below in console.

> Can't bind to 'ngIfElse' since it isn't a known property of 'p'.

I have give **isTrue2 = false** in module.

Below is my code for AngularJS 4 application.

```
<p *ngIf="isTrue2; else other">example</p>

<ng-template #other>
  other content here...
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Did you import `CommonModule` in the component's module?

Comment: Double-check your Angular version, most of the related questions I can find are caused by that.  Also post your module/component, it might be a missing import.

Comment: @Murhaf Sousli, I wrote too fast, forgot that you can also get this error if you didn't import correctly. I was probably thinking about not being able to use both *ngIf and *ngFor together on the same tag.

Comment: I have added import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common'; in module

Comment: Sad to see that this question was downvoted by Stackoverflow trolls. It's really ruining this site.

Answer (score 1):

If the component is declared in a sub module, make sure it imports `CommonModule`

Otherwise if the component is declared in the root module, then use `BrowserModule`

Here is a working [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Xxg2QaW1ZaHmtVCEt55F?p=preview)

Comment: I have added CommonModule also. still no use same error. The component is declared in root module.

Comment: @Vijay Don't import `CommonModule` in the root module! use `BrowserModule`